# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "suspend error at second"

Tags: suspend, lts, 16.04

please help me, i have problem with the suspend.
what ever i do to suspend via close lid or klik suspend button it running well at first. but the second suspend my laptop can't suspend properly, it just turn the lid black but my laptop isn't turn to suspend.
please help me.

Comment: My laptop asus k53sd spec : intel core i3-2350m, 2GB ram and nvdia geforce 610m. I use ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue. I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 5521.

This is a known bug in 16.04. You can follow the developments here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302.

Edit: Apparently there is a bug in the 4.4.0 kernel. The problem can be solved when you install the new kernel 4.4.8.

You can find instruction to do it here:
http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: After i install the kernel i accidentally remove my kernel and after restart cant boot to the linux. I will reinstall my linux and try again hiks. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Work perfectly